Terraform Azure Frontdoor Static Site
I am trying to create a simple static site with Terraform on Azure using storage and Frontdoor. I want to eventually have a serious web app running there. But for now I just want to access my index.html. If I hit the storage directly it works, but via the CDN I get a 400 invalid uri. What am I doing wrong?
# Storage Account to host static content
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  static_website {
    index_document     = "index.html"
    error_404_document = "error_404.html"
  }
}

# Front Door Profile
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile" "fd_profile" {
  name                = "${azurerm_storage_account.sa.name}-fdprofile"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku_name            = "Standard_AzureFrontDoor"
}

# Front Door Origin Group
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group" "fd_origin_group" {
  name                     = "${azurerm_storage_account.sa.name}-origingroup"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.fd_profile.id

  load_balancing {
    sample_size                 = 4
    successful_samples_required = 3
  }

  health_probe {
    path                = "/index.html"
    request_type        = "HEAD"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 100
  }
}

# Front Door Origin
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin" "fd_storage_origin" {
  name                           = "${azurerm_storage_account.sa.name}-origin"
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id  = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.fd_origin_group.id
  host_name                      = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_web_host
  origin_host_header             = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_web_host
  certificate_name_check_enabled = false
}

# Front Door Endpoint
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint" "fd_endpoint" {
  name                     = "${azurerm_storage_account.sa.name}-endpoint" # Change this to a unique name
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.fd_profile.id
}


# Front Door Route
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "fd_route" {
  name                          = "${azurerm_storage_account.sa.name}-route"
  cdn_frontdoor_endpoint_id     = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.fd_endpoint.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.fd_origin_group.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_ids      = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin.fd_storage_origin.id]

  patterns_to_match   = ["/*"]
  forwarding_protocol = "HttpsOnly"
  supported_protocols = ["Https", "Http"]

  cache {
    query_string_caching_behavior = "IgnoreQueryString"
    compression_enabled           = true
    content_types_to_compress     = ["text/html", "text/css", "application/javascript", "application/json"]
  }
}




Ok it just started working. Perhaps patience is the lesson. Should I delete this ?


Azure Frontdoor Static Site sync using terraform

Hello Brenwell, seems like you already found a solution to your problem, I am just posting it here for ease of other folks who are facing similar issue on SO. Please feel free to add any points / your inputs to this if required.
In general, '400 Invalid URI' occurs when a specific routing configuration that might occur during propagation delay. Make sure host_name and origin_host_header fields should match your storage account's static website hostname and mentioned correctly.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile" "fd_profile" {
  name                = "cssstorageact123-fdprofile"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku_name            = "Standard_AzureFrontDoor"
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group" "fd_origin_group" {
  name                     = "cssstorageacct123-origingroup"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.fd_profile.id

  load_balancing {
    sample_size                 = 4
    successful_samples_required = 3
  }

  health_probe {
    path                = "/index.html"
    request_type        = "HEAD"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 100
  }
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin" "fd_storage_origin" {
  name                           = "cssstorageacct123-origin"
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id  = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.fd_origin_group.id
  host_name                      = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_web_host
  origin_host_header             = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_web_host
  certificate_name_check_enabled = false
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint" "fd_endpoint" {
  name                     = "cssstorageacct123-endpoint"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.fd_profile.id
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "fd_route" {
  name                          = "cssstorageacct123-route"
  cdn_frontdoor_endpoint_id     = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.fd_endpoint.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.fd_origin_group.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_ids      = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin.fd_storage_origin.id]

  patterns_to_match   = ["/*"]
  forwarding_protocol = "HttpsOnly"
  supported_protocols = ["Https", "Http"]

  cache {
    query_string_caching_behavior = "IgnoreQueryString"
    compression_enabled           = true
    content_types_to_compress     = ["text/html", "text/css", "application/javascript", "application/json"]
  }
}

Deployment:



Refer:
azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/frontdoor
